# Vertically center elements in a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to keep my `div1` inner elements centered vertically.

As you can see in my `div1` `display`, if I use `display: table-cell` it aligns elements vertically but the elements go to the top and not centered.

But if I use `display: flex`, it keep the elements centered but the elements are aligned horizontally.

```css
.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.span1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #111;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-spacing: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
  max-height: 120px;
  dispaly: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underline {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">God Bless us all.</span>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c15dmfws/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a lot of unnecessary code. I cleaned it up a bit.

```css
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.span1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #111;
  word-spacing: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
  max-height: 120px;
}

.underline {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">God Bless us all.</span>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c15dmfws/1/)

Answer (score 2):

updated snippet

```css
.div1{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  background:white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.span1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #111;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-weight: 600;
    max-height: 120px;
    dispaly: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.underline{
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">God Bless us all.</span>
  <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Properly used `display: flex` solves your issue.

Use properties:

```
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
```

as in the example below:

```css
.one {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="one">
  
  <div class="two">
     hello
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 200px;
            width: 100px;
            display: table;
        }
        .div1 {
            
            background: white;
            display: flex;
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: table-cell;
        }
        
        .span1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #111;
            word-spacing: 100px;
            font-weight: 600;
            max-height: 120px;
            dispaly: block;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .underline {
            position: relative;
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            background: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="div1">
            <span class="span1">God Bless us all.</span>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set .div1 to display:table; not display:table-cell; ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/bn430he1/ , try this.

Wrap the content in another div, give that div css property of height:auto; and remove the display:table-cell; from div1

Hope it helps...

```
<div class="div1">
<div class="aligned">
  <span class="span1">God Bless us all.</span>
  <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.aligned {
  height:auto;
}

.div1{
  width:100px;
  background:white;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.span1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #111;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-weight: 600;
    max-height: 120px;
    dispaly: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.underline{
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```