# How to Vertically Position DIV Elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I am having problems positioning my content in CSS. I want to take my content and vertically position it. I have tried using flexbox but it didn't work. I know what flexbox is and it's properties but it didn't work for me. Here's the CSS and HTML Code.

HTML:

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="container-1">
    
        <h2>What is Your Age In Days?</h2>
        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click Me!</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Try Again</button> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="container-2">
        <h2>Generator</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="picture-generator" onclick=pictureGenerator()>GENERATE</button>

        <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="picture-gen">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url(Background.jpeg)
}


.container-1, .container-2 {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
}

.flex-box-container-1, .flex-box-container-2 {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-container-1 div {
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

#flex-box-result {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#yikes {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Animation-name: example;
    Animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;;
}

@keyframes example {
    10% {color: red;}
    15% {color: yellow;}
    20% {color: blue;}
    30% {color: green;}
    40% {color: lightsalmon;}
    50% {color: lightsteelblue}
    60% {color: steelblue}
    70% {color: ivory}
    80% {color: purple}
    90% {color: pink}
    100% {color: magenta;}
    }



.flex-box-container-2 img {
    box-shadow: -12px 11px 28px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.69);
    margin: 10px;
}
```

So, I have to vertically align container 1 and 2. I tried doing it with **Justify Content** and **Align Items** but it didn't work. I appreciate every single bit of help.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what result you are aimiing for. Are container 1 and container 2 to be next to each other? And in what sense vertically-aligned (the centers aligned or the tops or..).

Comment: Container 1 and 2 are next to each other. I want to vertically center them. If you want to see the code output, here is the js fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/y924rv7g/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically center elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391634/vertically-center-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: No it doesn't. I've tried using flexbox and it's properties but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Which elements do you want to be aligned? I understand that you want container-1 and container-2 next to each other, but which bits of their respective content do you want aligned with each other? The titles and/or the buttons?

Comment: I want to take the containers and vertically center them.

Comment: Maybe change `flex-direction: column;` and add `align-items: center;` in your  `.flex-box-container-1, .flex-box-container-2` class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flex-direction: column` to vertically position it.

Comment: I meant to vertically align it. I need to move it up and down.

Comment: You can try setting both Justify-Content and Align Items to center

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. It didn't work. If you want to see it for yourself, you can see the code on js fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/y924rv7g/

Answer (score 0):

If Flex doesn't work for you, there's two more ways of doing it, as far as I am aware.

The first one is using `display: table; width: 100%;` on the parent element, and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the children you want to vertically align.

The second one involves using `position: relative` on the parent element, and `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` on the children.

If you want to center both **container-1** and **container-2**, one on top of the other, you have to create another **div** which wraps these two. In this case, this would be your child element.

If you want the two containers to be next to each other, use bootstrap's grid system  to give them the appropriate **col** classes, and consider those two as the children.

In both of the above cases, your parent element should be **.main-div**.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help but I want to stick to using flexbox. I updated some of my code, you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/21mL930y/

Please inform me if you find a solution.